# Counting the elements of the quotient ring of a polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f\in\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ a non-constant, univariate,  integer polynomial $\mod n$. Let $(f)$ be the ideal generated by $f$ in $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$. Then, the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]\big/(f)$ is a finite ring.

I was wondering, how can we count the number of its elements?

Take for example, $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ and $f(x)=3x^2+1$. How many elements does the ring $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]\big/(3x^2+1)$ have?

**P.S.:** there is a relevant question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1610362/count-the-number-of-elements-of-ring)

Comment: Let the leading coefficient of $f(x)$ be $m$. 
The easy case for counting is when gcd$(m,n)=1$. In that case it is simply $n^m$. The quotient ring is a *free module* over $\mathbf{Z}_n$ with $1,x,x^2,\ldots x^{m-1}$ as a basis.

Comment: @P Vanchinathan: thank you for mentioning this. I guess you mean that $m$ is the "leading power" of $f(x)$ and not the leading coefficient. But then, why do you say that we need $m,n$ to be coprimes? Isn't this the same thing even if $\gcd(m,n)\neq 1$?